# Block from viewing source code

Tags: .htaccess

What is the most defensive way of blocking someone from viewing source code? I know people can still get to it -- but hopefully those of a lesser tech people cannot get to it?

It's .htaccess -- right?

Comment: What kind of source code: HTML/CSS/JavaScript or a server side script (PHP/Perl/Python/Ruby)?

Comment: Can't answer the question unless you tell us what kind of code you're trying to hide from who. And .htaccess is unlikely the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's .htaccess, you can use that to block access to your files all together.

- A very simple, maybe not so very effective way is to add a lot of blank lines at the top of your html file.
- Further you can obfuscate javascript (1) or minify (2) it (here to reverse (3))
- Blocking the right mouse click (4) with javascript
- If it's php source code you want to protect while still be able to distribute your source, you can try something like Zend Guard (5)

1: [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

2: http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

3: [Tool to reverse Javascript minify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028138/tool-to-reverse-javascript-minify)

4: [How to disable mouse right click on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083798/how-to-disable-mouse-right-click-on-a-web-page)

5: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score -3):

If you can't use .htaccess, it is pointless.  Anyone can just disable javascript in their browser and do it anyway.