# How to stop a browser from opening a dialogue box when a user clicks the right mouse button?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, canvas, mouse

I'm making a game, it uses the canvas element, and I need both of the mouse buttons. How can I stop the browser (I'd like it to run in most major ones, so, it's preferred that the solution is universal) from opening that dialogue box when the user presses the right mouse button. How can I do that in JavaScript? I tried this, but it does not work:

```
self.onClick = function(ev)
{
    if(ev.button == 2)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    var x = ev.clientX - self.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - self.canvas.offsetTop;
    input.mouse = {"button": ev.button, "click": true, "x": x, "y": y};
}
```

The global variable input is then sent to the server to be processed.

EDIT: it works now. I had to edit the canvas element (canvas oncontextmenu="return false")

Comment: Also, for anyone that really wants to know, I'm using Chrome to test stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable mouse right click on a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083798/how-to-disable-mouse-right-click-on-a-web-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.oncontextmenu` and call preventDefault on the event.

```
self.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Note that some users may not like you disabling their context menu.

Comment: It's an absolutely crucial part of the game, a way to move units and give them commands.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid that it doesn't work. Tested it on the newest version of Chrome for Linux.

Comment: @bane It works for me (Chrome on Windows): http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalPlane/pCTpQ/

Comment: works for me too now :)
I shall accept your answer, for it gave me a hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
self.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is onclick and not onClick

In this case use

`self.oncontextmenu=function() { return false }`

or

`self.oncontextmenu=function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }`

in plain JS

Comment: Strange, this doesn't work. I'm using the newest version of Chrome for Linux.

Comment: And the difference between this and the accepted answer is what??? and looking at your update, it looks like my first suggestion.

Comment: Well all the answers I got are the same, but I can't accept them all. I did give you one ups and stuff...

Comment: they may be the same, but they were answered at different times and I also explained a typo you had. Never mind...